# Movieclip not being removed from array or stage - AS3 - CS6

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, flash-cs6

my enemy movie clips are not being removed from the stage on collision/hitTestObject with the bullet movie clip, the bullets are being removed though, only the enemies that are not. Appreciate all help with this. Thanks you guys, your a brilliant community here, respect you loads.

I used the same code that made the bullet movie clips be removed for the enemies (though change changing the vars etc accordingly).

My code for Main.as and Enemy.as is here:

**Main.as**

```
package
{
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public var player:Player;
    public var enemy:Enemy;

    public var bulletList:Array = [];

    public var mousePressed:Boolean = false; //keeps track of whether the mouse is currently pressed down
    public var delayCounter:int = 0; //this adds delay between the shots
    public var delayMax:int = 7; //change this number to shoot more or less rapidly

    public var enemies:Array =  [];

    public function Main():void
    {
        player = new Player(stage, 320, 240);
        stage.addChild(player);

        //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootBullet, false, 0, true); //remove this
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
        for(var numBaddies=0; numBaddies<6;numBaddies++){
            var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(null);
            enemy.x = numBaddies*50;
            enemy.y = numBaddies*50
            stage.addChild(enemy);
            enemies.push(enemy);
        }
    }

    public function loop(e:Event):void
    {
        if(mousePressed) // as long as the mouse is pressed...
        {
            delayCounter++; //increase the delayCounter by 1
            if(delayCounter == delayMax) //if it reaches the max...
            {
                shootBullet(); //shoot a bullet
                delayCounter = 0; //reset the delay counter so there is a pause between bullets

           }
        }

        if(bulletList.length > 0)
        {
            for(var i:int = bulletList.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                bulletList[i].loop();
            }
        }

        for(var h = 0; h<bulletList.length; ++h)
        {
            if(bulletList[h].hitTestObject(this)){
              trace("player hit by baddie " + h);
               }
        }

        for(var u:int=0; u<enemies.length; u++) {
        Enemy(enemies[u]).moveTowards(player.x, player.y);
        }
    }


    public function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void //add this function
    {
        mousePressed = true; //set mousePressed to true
    }

    public function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void //add this function
    {
        mousePressed = false; //reset this to false
    }

    public function shootBullet():void //delete the "e:MouseEvent" parameter
    {
        var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(stage, player.x, player.y, player.rotation, enemies);
        bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, bulletRemoved, false, 0, true);
        bulletList.push(bullet);
        stage.addChild(bullet);
    }

    public function bulletRemoved(e:Event):void
    {
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, bulletRemoved);
        bulletList.splice(bulletList.indexOf(e.currentTarget),1);
    }
}
}
```

**Enemy.as**

```
package  {

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Enemy extends MovieClip {

    public var bullets:Array;

    public var stageRef:Stage;

    private var enemyPositionX, enemyPositionY,xDistance,yDistance,myRotation:int;
    public function Enemy(bulletList:Array) {
        // constructor code
        bullets = bulletList;
    }

    public function moveTowards(playerX:int, playerY:int){
        xDistance = this.x - playerX;
        yDistance = this.y - playerY;


        myRotation = Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance);

        this.x -= 3 * Math.cos(myRotation);
        this.y -= 3 * Math.sin(myRotation);


    }

    public function loop():void{

    for(var i=0; i<bullets.length; ++i)
        {
            if(bullets[i].hitTestObject(this)){
               trace("you killed enemy " + i);
               removeSelf();
               }
        }
    }

    private function removeSelf():void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        if (stageRef.contains(this))
        stageRef.removeChild(this);
    }
}

}
```

And for reference so you can see how I used the same code to remove the movie clips, I'll add the Bullet.as too:

**Bullet.as**

```
package
{
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Bullet extends MovieClip
{
    private var stageRef:Stage; //checks if the bullet leaves the screen borders
    private var speed:Number = 10; //speed that the bullet will travel at
    private var xVel:Number = 0; //current x velocity
    private var yVel:Number = 0; //current y velocity
    private var rotationInRadians = 0; //convenient to store our rotation in radians instead of degrees

    public var allBaddies:Array;

    //our constructor requires: the stage, the position of the bullet, and the direction the bullet should be facing
    public function Bullet(stageRef:Stage, X:int, Y:int, rotationInDegrees:Number, enemies:Array):void
    {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;
        this.rotation = rotationInDegrees;
        this.rotationInRadians = rotationInDegrees * Math.PI / 180; //convert degrees to radians, for trigonometry
        allBaddies = enemies;
    }

    public function loop():void //we don't need to include the "e:Event" because we aren't using an EventListener
    {
        for(var b=0; b<allBaddies.length; ++b)
        {
            if(allBaddies[b].hitTestObject(this)){
               trace("bullet hit baddie " + b);
               removeSelf();
               }
        }

        xVel = Math.cos(rotationInRadians) * speed; //uses the cosine to get the xVel from the speed and rotation
        yVel = Math.sin(rotationInRadians) * speed; //uses the sine to get the yVel

        x += xVel; //updates the position
        y += yVel;

        //if the bullet goes off the edge of the screen...
        if(x > stageRef.stageWidth || x < 0 || y > stageRef.stageHeight || y < 0)
        {
            this.parent.removeChild(this); //remove the bullet
        }
    }

    private function removeSelf():void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        if (stageRef.contains(this))
        stageRef.removeChild(this);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you get the trace from enemy?

Comment: If you mean the one in the statement for the enemy to be removed, no it wasn't in the output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are a couple of things I would change around, alongside a couple issues I noticed.

First, your `Enemy` class as far as I can tell never gets the `stageRef` variable set. Therefore in your `Enemy` class `removeSelf()` your `stageRef` will be null.

You can either pass the stage in through the constructor and set it (as you do in your bullet class), or you can set it after you instantiate in your enemies loop with `enemy.stageRef = stage`. Or you can add and event listener to your enemy class for `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` and when that happens your enemy will have a reference to the stage inherited.

Now, the real meat of the matter. You have 2 for loops testing for collision (aside from one in your `Main` class too, but I'll get to that). One is in your bullet class and one is in your enemy class. This is overkill and is difficult on performance if you start adding in lots of bullets and enemies.  You really only need a single for loop (like the one in your bullet class), and when it detects a collision it calls the collided objects remove method. That would look something like this in your `Bullet` class:

```
public function loop():void //we don't need to include the "e:Event" because we aren't using an EventListener
{
    for(var b=0; b<allBaddies.length; ++b)
    {
        if(allBaddies[b].hitTestObject(this)){
            trace("bullet hit baddie " + b);
            removeSelf();
            allBaddies[b].removeSelf();
        }
    }
```

Although, for this to work you would need to set the `removeSelf()` in your `Enemy` class access to public:

```
public function removeSelf():void
{
    //this is removing a listener not even added Enemy...
    //removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    if (stageRef.contains(this))
    stageRef.removeChild(this);
}
```

Then you can probably even eliminate your `loop()` from the `Enemy` class seeing as how all it does it detect collisions that will no longer be necessary.

Lastly as to why this might happened? Well it could be the bullet hitTest which is running first from your call in the main class: `bulletList[i].loop();` This hitTest is being detected, then removing the bullet leaving your Enemy class without an object to hit test against. BUT! you are not calling the `loop()` from enemy anywhere in your main class, therefore that hit test will never run.

It's best to condense your collisions down. You are currently looping through your `Bullet` instances in the main class, calling their `loop()` (which tests for collisions), and then afterwards doing a for loop doing the collision test again. You could change this:

```
if(bulletList.length > 0)
{
    for(var i:int = bulletList.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            bulletList[i].loop();
        }
    }
    //this is no longer needed...
        /*for(var h = 0; h<bulletList.length; ++h)
        {
            if(bulletList[h].hitTestObject(this)){
              trace("player hit by baddie " + h);
               }
        }*/
```

There is no reason to test the collision in the `Bullet` class AND in the `Main` class `loop(e:Event)`.

Hope this information helps! Good luck :)

Comment: Wow, you've done some extensive reading, much appreciated. I'm off to bed now because it's getting late but will certainly implement this tomorrow, I will let you know how it goes. Kind regards. :)

Comment: I get this error in `Enemy.as` `Enemy.as, Line 32, 1004: Namespace was not found or is not a compile-time constant.` This is after making all the suggested changes. If I change `removeSelf()` which is the error back to private rather than public I then get an error in `Main.as` on the same line number asking for 2 arguments when I declare the enemy var although It's been given `null` as the current args. Any ideas here? Thanks. :)

Comment: Line 32 is this piece of code `var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(null);`.

Comment: I asked you to post your code because `var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(null);` is not the problem. But since that is lacking information make sure that in the class you are instantiating a new Enemy ( I'm assuming your Main class ), in the package you have an import statement for your enemy class.